# Connecting 2 ethernet ports together via a patch panel

Tags: ethernet

I have in a building 2 different Ethernet faceplates both with unique numbers back to the main patch panel. What I am doing is transmitting hdmi over ethernet using HDMI extenders so one port is transmitting the HDMI signal over ethernet and the other will receive the hdmi singal. However I need to patch the 2 ports together at the patch panel with what I would assume is a crossover patch lead. The HDMI transmitter and receiver all works and I can receive the signal at the patch panel for the transmitting port but the receiving ethernet port is not working via the crossover patch to the actual faceplate. Is there something I am missing maybe with the crossover cable? The cable itself is T568A to T568B. Thanks.

Comment: In general: be specific in your questions, naming a brand and model is usually helpful in getting relevant answers, otherwise you might not get anything but questions back or  generic comments: One possibility: the sender and receiver are designed for a  direct cable connection and using a cross over cable is the wrong choice. But you can easily test that. Also: possibly the combined lengths of the two runs exceeds the supported cable distance? And then you'll need a repeater/hub or switch at the location of the patch panel?

Comment: I tested with an ethernet cable connected directly to both transmitter and receiver and it works. The length is well within the specific guidlines so do not think that is an issue.
The device is a  OREI HDMI Extender UltraHD.

Answer (score 5):

> What I am doing is transmitting hdmi over ethernet using HDMI extenders so one port is transmitting the HDMI signal over ethernet and the other will receive the hdmi singal.

It probably doesn't use Ethernet. It probably transmits HDMI over twisted pair cable, but it's *probably* not Ethernet.

> what I would assume is a crossover patch lead.

I would not assume that. I would assume a straight cable is needed. The device is probably not doing Ethernet, and it's probably made to work with the most common cable - which is a straight through cable.

Crossover cables haven't really been a thing for almost twenty years.

Comment: AFAIK both kinds of devices exist, using terminology like HDMI over CATx when then use their own protocols over a twisted pair cable with RJ45 connectors  but also HDMI over IP or gigabit when they encapsulate in conventional TCP/IP packets (but when the OP doesn't include enough relevant details in the question you need to guess and make assumptions)

Comment: I agree, but as it doesn't work over crossover cable my bet is on just using Cat cable as transport...

Comment: I tested with a straight through patch lead and it does not work. To be more specific I patched the ports together on the patch panel using a straight through cable. The devices are OREI HDMI Extender UltraHD. I dont think that the protocol that is being transmitted matters as once the physical Ethernet connection is there that is what it uses and it does work with a direct ethernet connection between the RX and TX devices.

Comment: [Your device](https://www.orei.com/products/uhd-ex165hk-hdmi-extender-165feet) is ***not*** using Ethernet. It happens to use Cat6 cabling. If it works with a straight patch cable between the two units, it does not require a crossover cable. Note that max distance is 165ft, and connectors introduce some extra loss, so you may very well be pushing the distance.

Comment: Essentially the question is do you need a crossover patch cable to connect 2 patch ports 
together to make both ends straight through. The protocol is not relevant.

Comment: Depends on the wiring. Probably not, as the standard is to use same wiring standard for both ends. My guess is that you're pushing signal quality.

Comment: "*The protocol is not relevant.*" - As long as you realize that these HDMI extenders do not use anything like Ethernet signals, so there must only be passive conductors (e.g. wire, plugs, sockets) connecting them. There can be no Ethernet switches or repeaters involved.